# How to open new browser window from Service Worker

Tags: javascript, notifications, service-worker

Is there a way to open new browser window from Service Worker like 
`window.open(...)`?

`Clients.openWindow()` or 
`WindowClient.navigate()`
 not something I need, and open new tab only.

Comment: send signal to client using postMessage asking to open a window. but I gues you will end with "popup blocked" message.

Comment: I use Push API, and there is no open tab when NotificationEvent appear, so there is no client to send postMessage

Comment: so, create new tab and open using it's window reference, then close.

Comment: Did you ever find out anything about this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear as to why you explicitly call out [`Clients.openWindow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow) as not being something you need, because what you describe is the intended use case for `Clients.openWindow()`. That's as close as you'll get to a solution.